# Plotting an image brightness graph along lines along the horizontal and vertical axis

Tags: python, image, plot, brightness

I have an image of a laser beam in png or tiff format. I need to plot the brightness/intensity of an image along a line along the horizontal and vertical axis (through the center of the beam). I tried to make an image in grayscale and take the brightness from there, but it turned out to be black in the center, although this is the most intense place. help me please
[image]
[image]
link to disk
https://disk.yandex.ru/d/jtoxC6amGz3nlw

I got a curve with a dip in the center, although the brightest place is in the center. (There should be a curve like Gaussian)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.